# react-hook-form custom resolver only checking after submit

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I'm building an abstract form component with react-hook-form and Yup for validation. The form works, and validation works, but only after the submit button is pressed.

It's on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-yup-validation-r2xye), but ...

```
import React, { cloneElement } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Controller, FormProvider, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { string as yupString, object as yupObject } from "yup";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  TextField
} from "@mui/material";

let renderCount = 0;

export const FormContent = ({ content }) => {
  return content.map((item, i) => {
    const name = item.component.props.name;

    return (
      <Controller
        key={name + "_" + i}
        name={name}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field, fieldState: { error }, formState: { isDirty } }) => {
          return cloneElement(item.component, {
            ...field,
            error: isDirty && !!error,
            helperText: isDirty && error?.message,
            FormHelperTextProps: { error: true }
          });
        }}
      />
    );
  });
};

export default function App() {
  renderCount++;

  const usernameInput = {
    validation: yupString().required("Username is required"),
    component: (
      <TextField required label="Username" name="username" type="text" />
    )
  };

  const passwordInput = {
    validation: yupString().required("Password is required"),
    component: <TextField required label="Password" name="password" />
  };

  const content = [usernameInput, passwordInput];

  let validationSchema = yupObject().shape({});

  // construct schema
  content.forEach((item) => {
    validationSchema = validationSchema.concat(
      yupObject().shape({
        [item.component.props.name]: item.validation
      })
    );
  });

  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });

  const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open>
      <Box>Render Count: {renderCount}</Box>

      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <Box component="form" onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}>
          <DialogContent>
            <FormContent content={content} />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              name="login"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="large"
            >
              Login
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Box>
      </FormProvider>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

If you type some data in the fields, and then erase the data without pressing the button, nothing happens. If you leave the fields empty and press the button, it gives the native component error message for required (i.e., it doesn't do the Yup resolving). But, if you enter some data, press the button, and then erase the data, then the Yup validation kicks in. How do I make it work before the button is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `required` prop from input components because otherwise native html validation will kick in.

And if you want start validation before pressing submit button you need to use some other `mode` for form, for example:

```
  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    mode: 'onChange' // or 'onBlur' for example
  });
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70956795-j7xyv?file=/src/App.js)

[More info in the docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform)